# Parse String Dates with different timezones

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs

I am trying to be able to take many strings with many different formats and in different timezones and turn them into either UTC or my localtime. I have tried the following and for some reason it has given me a hour off:

```
var moment = require('moment');
console.log(moment('Mon, 30 Sep 2013 18:00:00 EST').format()); //2013-09-30T16:00:00-07:00

console.log(new Date('Mon, 30 Sep 2013 18:00:00 EST')); //Mon Sep 30 2013 16:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)

console.log(new Date()); //Mon Sep 30 2013 15:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)
```

The only thing I can think of that could cause this is day light savings time but I am not sure. Any suggestions with how to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used the wrong time zone.  For an apples-to-apples comparison, use `EDT` (eastern daylight time):

```
> console.log(new Date('Mon, 30 Sep 2013 18:00:00 EDT'));
Mon Sep 30 2013 15:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)
```

which is what you would expect (3 hour difference)

Comment: Thanks I just actually saw this. Cant believe I did not see this

Comment: @Jacinto unfortunately JS date handling is awful (moment helps somewhat)